# How to hide div inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried the following which did not work:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#hide_this_div').hide(); 

$(function() {   
  var $head = $('frame').contents().find("head");                
  $head.append("<link/>", { 
    rel: "stylesheet", 
    href: "./hide_the_div.css", 
    type: "text/css" 
  });
})
```

```css
#hide_the_div {
  display: none;
}
```

I am trying to hide the `.timestamp` class in this iframe:

```
<iframe  src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comment_embed.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FScrapbookingCoach%2Fvideos%2F318198945603068%2F%3Fcomment_id%3D331374627618833&include_parent=false" width="560" height="141" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="yes" frameborder="15" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

Comment: your CSS references the id `hide_the_div`, but in your JS it's `hide_this_div`. These are not the same. Does fixing that make it work?

Comment: What is inside the iframe - is it content loaded from your own domain, or a different one?

Comment: Your first line of code seems to be outside the document.ready handler, so will run before the DOM is ready. Move it inside. Also note that if the content of the iframe is on a different domain to the parent window you will not be able to do what you require here. Check the console for errors to confirm this

Comment: I already tried that.

Comment: No none of what you guys said worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

For example, if you want to hide `h1` from `<iframe>`

```
<iframe id="myFrame" src="#" style="height:380px;width:100%"></iframe>


function myFunction() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  var element = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  element.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Please attribute your code if you didn't write it yourself: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_element_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait for iframe is loaded.

```
$('#my_iframe').ready(function(){
  console.log('load the iframe')
  var $timestamp = $('#my_iframe').find(".timestampContent");
  $timestamp.hide();
});
```